# Where is 'Payment Method' stored in the database for a Contribution "Payment Details"?

Tags: civicontribute, database

Simple question! What table is this in, where do I find it? Latest Civi/Drupal

[image]

This is on a contribution detail page. I updated the payment_instrument_id in civicrm_contribute but it does not change it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The payment method of a contribution table is stored on the `civicrm_financial_trxn` table. Payments and Contributions are related through `civicrm_entity_financial_trxn` table.

Some discussions about similar issues have recently taken place on [financial issue board](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues?sort=updated_desc). Please consider whether you can make a contribution on any of them or if you need to report a new one.